# Ruby - Converting Small Float Numbers to String

Tags: ruby, string, floating-point, scientific-notation

I've noticed that small number floats, like 0.00000000345 end up getting converted to scientific notation, ie, 3.45e-9.  This makes sense, but it looks like if I convert the float to a string (as I'd like to manipulate specific elements of the float according to its contents), the string itself adopts this notation.

Since it's now a string, it's easy enough to "translate" the contents back to a proper decimal number and manipulate it, but I was wondering if there is a built-in way that automatically allows for the saving of the actual decimal number as a string, rather than the scientific notation.  Might not be, and I don't see anything in the documentation, but it can't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a round-trip to [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/BigDecimal.html) you can use its [`to_s`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s) method which allows the output format to be explicitly specified:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

float = 0.00000000345
#=> 3.45e-09

float.to_d.to_s('F')
#=> "0.00000000345"
```

Note that [`Float#to_d`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Float.html#method-i-to_d) attempts to determine the precision automatically which might fail for certain numbers:

```
float = 1.0.next_float
#=> 1.0000000000000002

float.to_d.to_s('F')
#=> "1.0"
```

Here, it might help to convert the float to a string in advance: (you also don't need to require `bigdecimal/util` using this variant)

```
BigDecimal(float.to_s).to_s('F')
#=> "1.0000000000000002"
```

---

Keep in mind that those outputs don't show the float's actual value. The *exact* decimal value for `0.00000000345` as a [double-precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is:

```
0.000000003449999999999999873659487851216588760738801511251949705183506011962890625
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sprintf`

```
small_number = 0.00000000345
formatted_string = sprintf("%.10f", small_number)    
p formatted_string
```

Output

```
"0.0000000034"
```

In this example, `"%.10f"` is a format specification for the `sprintf` function. The `%f` specifies that the argument should be formatted as a floating-point number, and `.10` specifies that the number should be represented with 10 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: So you need to know the number of digits in advance?

Comment: Given problem appears that way.